# Load data from mysql to leaflet

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, leaflet

I need to make a map leaflet that contains some polygons and i want to color my poygons based on data from MYSQL. But when i try this code, my polygons are not show.
This is my code on my map.php:

```
<?php
    include 'koneksi.php';
    $sql="select sum(skor_bobot) as hasilnya from penilaian where bulan=1 and id_kelurahan=1";
    $data=mysql_query($sql);
    $js='';
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
        $js .='L.geoJson(states, {
    style: function(feature) {
        if ((feature.properties.party=='.'Republican'.')&&('.$row['hasilnya'].'=='.'10'.')) {
             return {color: "#ffff89"};
        } else {
            return {color: "#ff0000"};
        };
    }
}).addTo(mymap);';
    }
    echo $js; ?>
```

and below are my geojson code on my map.php:

```
var states = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {"party": "Republican"},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-104.05, 48.99],
            [-97.22,  48.98],
            [-96.58,  45.94],
            [-104.03, 45.94],
            [-104.05, 48.99]
        ]]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {"party": "Democrat"},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-109.05, 41.00],
            [-102.06, 40.99],
            [-102.03, 36.99],
            [-109.04, 36.99],
            [-109.05, 41.00]
        ]]
    }
}];
```

Comment: did you have seen browser console for error log?

Comment: I would change my strategy and handle the server side of things separate to the front end. PHP to query your DB and return a geojson when requested through an AJAX call. This way you can debug your db, your geojson and your js code separately.

Comment: @NafianWildana browser console said "Uncaught ReferenceError: Republican is not defined". but when i use if else without db, my polygons were shown.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that you do not (double) quote `Republican` in your JS code?

```
'(feature.properties.party=='.'"Republican"'.')'
```

Without those double quotes, once your code is executed as JavaScript, you are passing a variable `Republican` (which you have not previously defined, hence your console error), instead of a *String* `"Republican"` to compare with.